# How to register (or ideally self-register) a Facebook app developer without forcing a "friendship" with an owner/admin

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, oauth

Our team is building an app that has Facebook login requirement (in addition to other oauth/identity providers such as LinkedIn, Google, end so on).
The app is obviously in the sandbox mode, so in order to develop/play with it, it requires developer accounts for each team member, otherwise login flow just fails.

My problem is that, as an app "owner" I don't see a way how to register developers or testers that are not in my friend list. I tried to put an e-mail address of one of my colleagues that she is using for facebook account, but Facebook did not accept it with the message that user id could not be resolved.  And I really do not want "to friend" with anyone. Making the app live is not an option either as it required review process, and we are pretty far from finishing this.

So is there any solution?

**Update**: Here is the error message shown to the user when she is not registered as a developer:

> App Not Setup: The developers of this app have not set up this app
>   properly for Facebook Login.

Comment: Did you try adding the user ID? that field should accept user ID (any user) or be a typeahead search for your friends

Comment: Yes, we tried an id returned by [API Exlplorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/) and, it did not work which is kind of expected as I believe Facebook has separate user id spaces per app. So is there such a thing as universal user id and if so where to get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. An app owner can use an alias that comes with the "facebook email" (whatever is in front of @facebook.com)
To access this special id, you need to go through the set of links:

- Your profile page
- Then click About
- Then click "Contact and Basic info"
- Then click on emails link to show your emails (emails hidden from Timeline)
- Then find @facebook.com email and take the part before the @ and use it
  for registering

Comment: Don't forget to 'self accept' this by clicking the tick mark to the left of the question (it may prevent you from doing this until another day has passed though).